# How does sceneKit deal with various screen sizes?

Tags: ios, game-physics, scenekit, screen-size

How does sceneKit deal with various screen sizes? Do geometries become bigger on larger screens? Does camera angle become bigger and wider? Do physics simulations look exactly the same on various phones? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do geometries become bigger on larger screens?

Nope, geometry size will be the same size, in the arbitrary unit you use (Meters by default). They will however appear bigger/smaller on screen but the size is the same (see next answer).

> Does camera angle become bigger and wider?

Slightly. The FOV adapts on an axis to fit the aspect of the screen. You can try that out by running your app on the resizable simulator and see how it reacts.

> Do physics simulations look exactly the same on various phones?

Yes and no. Overall, the simulation will feel the same (weight, speed, behaviour), but in details the randomness of the physics engine and the differences in hardware will make the simulations slightly different and random every time.